# Two argument V() with ground

Tags: ngspice

As part of a project, I am writing a program which generates ngspice scripts. For my purposes, it would be very convenient if I could always use the two argument v() instead of using v(node) when I want to compare against ground and v(node1,node2) when I want to use two arbitrary nodes. When I execute "listing", it shows a ".global gnd", but v(node,gnd) returns

```
Error(parse.c--checkvalid): gnd: no such vector.
```

Is there a way to get a vector of zeros, or must I hardcode both cases independently?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cannot find why you can't refer a voltage with respect to gnd, like v(node1,gnd).

However, as work around, you could make a node called psuedoground (or whatever you want to name it), connecting it to a voltage source of 0V as follows:

```
use psuedoground netlist
...
V999 0 psuedoground 0
...
```

This way, a voltage source V999 is connected between ground node named '0' and the node named psuedognd with value 0V, making psuedognd effectively equal to gnd.

Now, you can use always 2 arguments with v(): V(node1, node2) or v(node1, psuedognd).

Note that `0` and `gnd` is the same.
From the [manual](http://ngspice.sourceforge.net/docs/ngspice-30-manual.pdf)

> The ground node must be named ‘0’ (zero). For compatibility reason gnd is accepted as ground node, and will internally be treated as a global node and be converted to ‘0’.

---

If you plot v(node1,psuedoground) you'll see that very name `v(node1,psuedoground)` in the plot as well.
In ngspice, you could also name the node `00` instead of `psuedognd` above as per manual

> Note the difference in ngspice where the nodes are treated as character strings and not evaluated as numbers, thus ‘0’ and 00 are distinct nodes in ngspice but not in SPICE2.